# I18n in Rails 3 with a admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I am developing an Rails app on the advice of the Rails Guides to create the folder tree and files with the translations.
My folder tree is similar to this:

```
|-defaults
|---es.rb
|---en.rb
|-models
|---book
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
|-views
|---defaults
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
|---books
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
|---users
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
|---navigation
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
```

The content in config/locales/views/books/en.yml is similar to this:

```
es:
 books:
  index:
   title: "Título"
```

A in inside app/views/books/index.html.erb template like this (note the dot):

```
<%= t '.title' %>
```

When I have no namespace my translations in views work well but with the namespace "admin" that I use in my backend it does not work. Anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I am using `<%= t '.title' %>` because I am using **“Lazy” Lookup** http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#lazy-lookup.

Rails implements a convenient way to look up the locale inside views. When you have the following dictionary:

```
es:
  books:
    index:
      title: "Título"
```

you can look up the books.index.title value inside app/views/books/index.html.erb template like this (note the dot):

```
<%= t '.title' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the namespace in your yaml as well:

```
es:
  admin:
    books:
      index:
        title: "Título"
```

Then you access the string with `<%= t '.title' %>` in your view.
I have just tested this with Rails 4.0.x

Answer (score -1):

You should only need to use the :scope operator as documented here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations

(I am not sure why you're using the `<%= t '.title' %>` with the dot -- you should either use a string that represents the field name (`<%= t 'title' %>`) or a symbol (`<%= t :title %>`).)